# Calculating correlation between elements in groups

Tags: correlation, odds-ratio

I'm analysing results from a lexical availability test. So I have groups of related words (each group is a single answer from an individual). [A,B,C,D],[B,A,E,F,G],[G,A,D,B,H]... and so on, where the letters represent words.

I'd like to analyse the relationship (distance) between each pair of words over all the answers. For example, 'cat' and 'dog' usually appear together, 'monkey' and 'chimp' too. But I'm having problems taking in account the frequency of each word individually. Very common words tend to appear very related but that happens just because they are very common and appear together a lot of times. I'd like to give a better score if words appear at distance 1 (one next to another) than distance 2,3..

How could I analyse this? I think I should use something similar to an odds ratio, but I don't know how to insert the relative distance between words in each group to the equation.